# Dynamic join of some filters in django

Tags: django, filter, models

I want to get three fields form user,

- two fields are database fields
- one is a radio box for mode of joining of these fields i.e. and/or

. The problem is that i don't know how to join these two filter based on the join filed.

I want to use a line that can tell **field1** join **filed2**, where join is the variable of user specified join mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the third field when querying the database.
The form for the filter could be like:

### forms.py

```
CHOICES = (
    ('and', 'And'),
    ('or', 'Or'),
)

class FilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_one = forms.CharField()
    field_two = forms.CharField()
    query_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = [
            'field_one',
            'field_two',
            'query_type',
        ]
```

And on your ListView you could do like:

### views.py

```
from django.db.models import Q

class YourListView(ListView):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super(YourListView, self).get_queryset(**kwargs)

        query_type = self.request.GET.get("query_type")
        field_one = self.request.GET.get("field_one")
        field_two = self.request.GET.get("field_two")

        if query_type == 'and':
            queryset = queryset.filter(field_one=field_one, field_two=field_two)
            
        elif query_type == 'or':
            queryset = queryset.filter( 
                Q(field_one=field_one)
                | Q(field_two=field_two)
            )
        return queryset
```

Note that you have to use GET on your form, for the filter html

Comment: thanks, i get two fields + the operator from user, and using an if, easily i combine them. But i want a more straight way. So i get two fields in two python variables. These Query sets can be combine using &/| without any problem, but the problem is that i can't use among them a variable to put specified join without conditional if.